# Small gaps appear when combining arcs and rectangles

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying simulate a corner by a series of small angular arcs and rectangles.

When it renders with anti-aliasing turned on, I get a picture like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nbWW.png

When I turn anti-aliasing off, I get the following picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7bDf.png

It almost looks as if my computations are off by a pixel or two, but I'm using doubles for all of the rendering, so I don't even think that is the case.

The code for the class is here:

http://pastebin.com/1SHu7rH0

It's not a huge issue with it, as the lines are hardly a distraction or serious error of calculation, but it is something that I would like to be able to fix, if at all possible.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't get a decent solution soon, I think that your best bet at getting one from us is to create a small compilable and runnable program that doesn't contain any code unrelated to the problem but that demonstrates the problem. This code would have no "model" or "control" code or dependencies on such, it wouldn't need outside data or images, but would just try to draw some lanes with curves using hard-coded data. This process is called creating an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and would involve a fair bit of effort on your part, but again if no answer is forth coming, the effort is worth it.

Comment: what is the question? and why not simply turn anti-aliasing on?

Comment: @kleopatra I did in the end. I couldn't figure out a solution to this in the end. I'll just have to make do with the little lines in between the curved segments.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: actually the problem might be using only fill(Shape): it only fills the interior. Calling draw(Shape) as well might fix the Shapes not lining up.

Why aren't you painting the bends as a single shape?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestDonut extends JPanel {
    public TestDonut() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Ellipse2D.Double gap = new Ellipse2D.Double(25, 25, 50, 50);
        Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100);
        Shape quarter = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50);
        Area donut = new Area(circle);
        donut.subtract(new Area(gap));
        Area quarterDonut = new Area(quarter);
        quarterDonut.subtract(donut);

        Area bend = new Area(quarter);
        bend.subtract(quarterDonut);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(bend);

        Path2D.Double bend2 = new Path2D.Double();
        bend2.moveTo(0, 50);
        bend2.quadTo(0, 0, 50, 0);
        bend2.lineTo(50, 25);
        bend2.quadTo(25, 25, 25, 50);
        bend2.closePath();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(bend2);

        Arc2D.Double outerArc = new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 90, Arc2D.PIE);
        Arc2D.Double innerArc = new Arc2D.Double(25, 25, 50, 50, 0, 90, Arc2D.PIE);
        Area bend3 = new Area(outerArc);
        bend3.subtract(new Area(innerArc));
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        ((Graphics2D) g).fill(bend3);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(new TestDonut());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```